# Cannot get child DIV % height to work because of parent margin auto

Tags: html, css

Am working within an existing framework so am limited in the CSS / HTML that I can edit. I have two child DIV's in a parent that I want to be 80% and 20% of the height of the parent. However, as the parent has 'margin: auto;' I am unable to get the height to work.

Can anyone help please? I know I could use JS to fix this, but have a strong preference not to. Would prefer a CSS fix if possible.

Please note that because I am working within a 3rd party product framework I cannot change the HTML or CSS beyond the areas marked.

See jsFiddle for an example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/6vb5910m/

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="flexer">
        <div class="template-container">
            <div class="template-contents">
            <!-- Cannot change anything above this line -->

                    <div class="ztop" style="background: rgb(200,0,0,0.3);">
                        I am 80% of Parent Height
                    </div>
                    <div class="zbottom"  style="background: rgb(0,200,0,0.3);">
                        I am 20% of Parent Height
                    </div>

            <!-- Cannot change anything below this line -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: height:100% to `.template-contents` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering so far. As mentioned in individual comments, making changes to .template-container or .template-contents is not something that I want to do. Technically, I could, but that would have a negative knock-on effect on other components on the page that are not within my control. Are there any ideas or suggestions or tricks that I can use to overcome the fact that there is no height set on the parent and fill the space allocated by the parents parent!

Comment: is the height of the parent element fixed to that specific value?

Comment: No, not fixed. I just fixed for the example. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent has an `auto` height, I'm afraid this is not possible.

The parent will always extend to contain all the children, so its height depends on the height of the children.

If your children also depend on the parent height, you have a infinite loop.

I think the only solution is to go with some Javascript, with which you can get the parent height dynamically and apply the right height to the children.

Or maybe if you don't need the `auto` height on this page you can override the `template-contents`'s height directly in the source so it does not apply to other pages ?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="flexer">
            <div class="template-container">
                <div class="template-contents">
                <!-- Cannot change anything above this line -->

                    <style>
                        .template-contents {
                            height: 100%;
                        }
                    </style>

                    <div class="ztop" style="background: rgb(200,0,0,0.3);">
                        I am 80% of Parent Height
                    </div>
                    <div class="zbottom"  style="background: rgb(0,200,0,0.3);">
                        I am 20% of Parent Height
                    </div>

                <!-- Cannot change anything below this line -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had hoped that maybe there was a trick of some sort, but it seems that is not the case. I will have to look at a bit of hacking of the source as you suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your percentage height is not working because your parent don't have any height :)

Just add `height: 100%;` to `.template-contents` and it'll work :

```css
.template-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

.template-contents {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.ztop {
  height: 80%;
}

.zbottom {
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="flexer">
    <div class="template-container">
      <div class="template-contents">
        <!-- Cannot change anything above this line -->

        <div class="ztop" style="background: rgb(200,0,0,0.3);">
          I am 80% of Parent Height
        </div>
        <div class="zbottom" style="background: rgb(0,200,0,0.3);">
          I am 20% of Parent Height
        </div>

        <!-- Cannot change anything below this line -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, .template-contents and .template-container are part of the 3rd party framework, so any changes that I make to them will have an undesirable knock-on effect to other content displayed on the page (that is not mine). So, I am constrained to only changing the css/html that I have highlighted in the example!

Answer (score 0):

Use height 100% into the parent element.

```
.template-contents {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or change the margin to 0 auto

```
.template-contents {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Please see my comments on previous answer. Unfortunatley I cannot make changes to .template-contents and .template-container.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the CSS even when you can't change the HTML. So just add this

```
.template-contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This keeps the horizontal margin auto, but removes the vertical.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Please see my comments on previous answer. Unfortunatley I cannot make changes to .template-contents and .template-container.